# Why cant I unwrap this optional value using Swift?

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

I am trying to get the value for first record which is "2018-05-04 09:00:00 +0000". When I print out `firstRecord', I get an optional value in the terminal:

> optional(2018-05-04 09:00:00 +0000).

Then I tried to unwrap it like so:

```
if dailyArray.count == 0 {
    print("no record was found")
}else{
    guard let firstRecord : String = dailyArray[0]["startTime"] as! String else {return}
    let firstRecordArray = firstRecord.components(separatedBy: " ")
    print("data exist \(firstRecordArray[0])")
}
```

And now Xcode is giving me an error saying that you are trying to unwrap a none optional value.

Any idea where am I making a mistake?

Comment: What type has `dailyArray`? What is the exact error message? – Could it be that the string "optional(...)" is stored in the dictionary, i.e. the problem occurs already when *creating* the dictionary?

Comment: `optional(..)` with a lower case "o"? How did you create that Dictionary/Array? Could you print `firstRecord.utf16.count`?

Comment: The `as!` does force unwrapping, so it's not an optional. Use `as?`.

Comment: That output suggests that you actually have a `Date` value, not a `String` value.

Comment: @rmaddy It might either be a `Date` or a `String`, but then it would have crashed with the force cast if it was a `Date` object. So as suggested the creation of it might be wrong, and the unwrap should have been done there. Even if the lower case "o" seems strange.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
guard !dailyArray.isEmpty, let firstRecord = dailyArray[0]["startTime"] as? String else { return }
let firstRecordArray = firstRecord.components(separatedBy: " ")
print("data exist \(firstRecordArray[0])")
```

In your code you are typecasting forcely thatswhy

```
["startTime"] as! String
```

this means that the value is **Strictly** string while **?** says it can be string

Comment: I have tried this too. It removes the error but does not produce any output :|

Comment: Are you sure dailyArray[0]["startTime"] is not nil and that it's actually a String type (and not a Date)? If you need to debug, you should decompose the guard statement into a series of guard statements to figure out which one is failing. Being able to chain guard statements is great, but it makes debugging harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining and the if let syntax to unwrap the variable and make the code much more concise and clear:

```
// dailyArray should be declared as or typecast to [[String : String]]

guard !dailyArray.isEmpty else {
    print("no record was found")
    exit(1) // or return if in func
}

if let firstRecord = dailyArray.first?["startTime"]?.components(separatedBy: " ") {
    print("data exists: \(firstRecord.first)")
}
else {
    print("no start time date was found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use optional chaining, then you may as well use `.first` (returns an optional, `nil` on empty array) rather than `[0]` (returns value, crashes on empty array):

```
guard !dailyArray.isEmpty else {
    print("no record was found")
    return
}
guard let firstRecord = dailyArray.first?["startTime"] as? String else {
    return
}
let firstRecordArray = firstRecord.components(separatedBy: " ")
print("data exist \(firstRecordArray[0])")
```